# ¿Cómo oculto una columna de mi DataTable sin perder sus valores?

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, web, datatable

me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación en java web. Estoy usando dataTables para listar los registros de mis tablas. Hasta aquí todo OK, puedo listar, crear y eliminar. Pero para editar necesito capturar los ID de las llaves foráneas.

[image]

Esa lista es de mi tabla "Insumos" pero tengo 2 tablas(categoría,unidad) que arrastro solo el nombre para mostrar al cliente. Necesito capturar los IDs de ambas tablas para que al momento de querer editar una de mis filas. Pueda mostrarle en el modal, todos los datos capturados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para hacer el selected con ese valor necesito sus IDs y solo se me ocurre capturarlo desde cada fila de mi dataTable.

Intenté con:

```
tablaInsumos.column(2).visible(0);
```

Funciona, sí, pero tambien oculta sus valores u.u. Alguien sabe cómo ocultarlos sin perder dicho valor? Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar esto y no repetir la clase en cada fila podes usar colgroup y col te dejo un ejemplo

```
 <table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="codigo hide_me">
    <col class="categoria">
    <col class="nombre-de-insumo">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>codigo</th>
    <th>categoria</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3476896</td>
    <td>Cuero</td>
    <td>sintetico negro</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Luego aplicas css para ocultar la columna correspondiente.
`.hide_me { display: none; }`

Comment: Hola Ruben, gracias por tu respuesta. Es una muy buena opción para no repetir en todas las filas. Sin embargo, me acabo de dar cuenta que el mismo archivos js se encarga de ocultarlas, por lo que ya no sería necesaria poner la etiqueta en la columna de la tabla. Tambien el cuerpo de mi tabla se genera dinámicamente. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la solución y la voy a compartir para aquellos que tengan el mismo problema.

Lo primero que deben hacer es agregar un class es la columna que deseen ocultar. Por ejemplo:

Esta para mi es mi columna #2

```
<th class="hide_me">Nombre de Insumo</th>
```

Luego en su css agreguen lo siguiente:

```
th.hide_me, td.hide_me {
display: none;
```

}

Por último agregar en su js:

```
"aoColumnDefs": [ { "sClass": "hide_me", "aTargets": [ 2 ] } ]
```

Deben tener en cuenta que yo estoy ocultando la columna 2 como ejemplo. Con esto ya debería funcionar.

Comment: Gracias genio, llevo 2 dias buscando esto, hiciste de mi una persona mas feliz :)